# "Dependent Name is not a Type", but prefixing with "typename" causes compiler crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

**Please see the updated code after the break;**

I have the following templated class:

```
template<class T> class CDFAManListOps
{
    static std::list<T>::iterator CDFAManListOps::GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, int pId)
    {
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it, it says

`std::list<T>::iterator' : dependent name is not a type 1> prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type`.

But if I change the function like the compiler asks me to:

```
static typename std::list<T>::iterator CDFAManListOps::GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, int pId)
```

the compiler (VS12) crashes with the following error:

`fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

`1> (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1443)`

`1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.`

Any idea what's wrong with this code?

---

**UPDATE:** This is the entirety of the smallest amount of code that I could get that reproduces this crash.

```
#include <list>

template<class T> class CDFAManListOps
{
    static typename std::list<T>::iterator CDFAManListOps::GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, int pId)
    {
    }

    static typename std::list<T>::iterator CDFAManListOps::GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, T object)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

If I take out **EITHER** of the two `GetIterator` functions, the program compiles and runs fine. Only when BOTH functions are present will the compiler crash. Does this make it any clearer what the problem in my code is?

<strike>(Also, I will be filing a bug report with Microsoft Connect and posting the link here if anyone wants to keep up with its status.)</strike>

I have filed a bug report on Microsoft Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794182/dependent-name-is-not-a-type-but-prefixing-with-typename-causes-compiler-crash).

**UPDATE:** Microsoft has decided **not** to do anything about this particular bug in the foreseeable future. See the Microsoft Connect link above.

Comment: See what happens if you put `typename` before the std::list inside the parameter list as well...

Comment: If you get a compiler crash, something's wrong with the compiler. It would be helpful if you could reduce your code to the smallest compileable snippet that still reproduces the crash and file a bug with Microsoft.

Comment: And regardless of any errors in your code, the compiler shouldn't be crashing like that. You should definitely report this as a bug.

Comment: Adding typename before the std::list in the params didn't help; it still crashed with the same error. :/ I'm not sure how I'll go about getting an iterator from a list of any type then... Maybe I'll make that a separate question.

Comment: And ok, I'll report it as a bug. Do they still use Microsoft Connect for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with the given code in MSVS2012.
This compiles fine:

```
#include <list>
template<class T> 
class CDFAManListOps
{
public:
  static typename std::list<T>::iterator GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, size_t pId)
  {
    typename std::list<T>::iterator it = list->begin();
    for (size_t i=0; i<pId; ++i) ++it;
    return it;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::list<size_t> x(5);
  CDFAManListOps<size_t>::GetIterator(&x, 2);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Ok, I can reproduce the problem now. Removing `CDFAManListOps::` from your in-class definition will result in correct compilation of your code.

```
#include <list>
template<class T> class CDFAManListOps
{
    static typename std::list<T>::iterator GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, int pId) {}
    static typename std::list<T>::iterator GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, T object) {}
};
int main() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually realized that you can't reproduce the problem unless you have a **second** method of the same return type in the class. See my update.

Comment: If you remove the class name from your declaration this will compile.

Comment: Your updated solution worked!! Ok, opinion: should we leave the question and answer the way they are, or should we edit them? i.e. get rid of the first part of my question (that doesn't actually produce a crash) and the first part of your answer? Would that help with clarity for people who stumble across this in the future because they don't have to sift through the extraneous stuff?

Comment: I think we may leave it the way it is. If people are at least at little clever they will find the problem and the proper solution (if marked as such). :)

Comment: Ok :) Probably for the best just to emphasize the fact it only happens if you have **both** methods in there. And don't worry, I'll accept your answer lol. I like how smoothly you slipped that reminder in there.

Comment: That wasn't the purpose of the supplement. I just wanted to stress that I don't think anyone will miss the answer if marked but perhaps may think "has no solution" (without further reading) if reading the question/comments without my answer being marked as solving the issue.

Comment: No problem! That wasn't a sarcastic/annoyed comment, more admiring than anything :)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try `typedef`ing the iterator type as a class member before the function declaration:

```
template<class T> class CDFAManListOps
{
    typedef typename std::list<T>::iterator iter_t;
    static iter_t GetIterator(std::list<T>* list, int pId)
    {
    }
};
```

or fully specify the list type:

```
template<class T> class CDFAManListOps
{
    template <typename Allocator>
    static typename std::list<T, Allocator>::iterator GetIterator(std::list<T, Allocator>* list, int pId)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, so the first solution doesn't change anything; the compile still crashes with the same message. The second solution gives me `error C3856: 'CDFAManListOps<T>::GetIterator': class is not a class template`.