# Type and Dependent Name

Tags: c++, templates, types

Manually I can create a `std::vector<int>::iterator` object like:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i;
```

So here `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a type. But when I write a function :

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T>::iterator foo(std::vector<int>::iterator i)
{
    return i;
}
```

The compiler shows a warning :

```
std::vector<T>::iterator' : is a dependent name  not a type
```

and the code does not compiles. But if in main I call the function like this:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    foo(v.begin());
}
```

The parameter `T` should be resolved. Then why compiler is showing error?

Answer (score 3):

Following link has a solution and answer,

["Dependent Name is not a Type", but prefixing with "typename" causes compiler crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684603/dependent-name-is-not-a-type-but-prefixing-with-typename-causes-compiler-cr)

In short, "std::vector::iterator" is a dependent name not a typename. So you can not use directly as a typename. You have to specify "typename std::vector::iterator".

Answer (score 2):

You have to prefix it with Typename
`std::vector<T>::iterator` is dependent on a template parameter, namely `T`.Therefore,you should prefix with it typename:
Try using:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator
```

You can refer This :http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers provided really explains why typename is necessary in this context. I've faced the same problem when working on the following code:

```
template<typename C>
vector<typename C::iterator> find_all(C& c, C::value_type v) {

    vector<typename C::iterator> res;

    for (auto p = c.begin(); p != c.end(); ++p) {
        if (*p == v)
            res.push_back(p);
    }

    return res;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the message "missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'C::value_type'". Of source if I change the signature to this:

```
vector<typename C::iterator> find_all(C& c, typename C::value_type v) {
```

it compiles without a problem. If the compiler can figure out C& c, why can't it figure out C::value_type?