# C++ returning protected struct pointer in template class

Tags: c++

Please help me I don't know what happens. It shows 
error C2955: 'MyClass' : use of class template requires template argument list

```
template <class T> class MyClass
{
protected:
    struct MyStruct
    {
    };

    MyStruct* GetElement(...) const;
}

//error C2955: 'MyClass' : use of class template requires template argument list
//I tried: 
// MyClass<T>::MyStruct* MyClass<T>::GetElement(...) const
// MyStruct* MyClass<T>::GetElement(...) const
// but none works. This method doesn't use T.
template<class T>
MyClass::MyStruct* MyClass<T>::GetElement(...) const
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `GetElement` should be written as `typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct*`:

```
template<class T>
typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct* MyClass<T>::GetElement(...) const
{

}
```

The `<T>` is necessary because `MyClass` is a [template class](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html).  `typename` is needed because `MyClass<T>::MyStruct` is a [dependent name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20368837/2555451).

Answer (score 1):

[These fixes work](http://ideone.com/B9ho2Q)

```
template <class T> class MyClass {
protected:
    struct MyStruct
    {
    };

    MyStruct* GetElement(...) const;
}; // << add semicolon

template <class T>
// Add typename
typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct* MyClass<T>::GetElement(...) const {
     // Add <T> ^^^
    return NULL;
}
```

Any type that depends on the template parameter must be specified with `typename`.